# Duda sobre un useState como objeto con arrays

Tags: reactjs, react-native

tengo una pequeña duda, tengo un estado como este

```
const [searchItems, setSearchItems] = useState({
    videos: [],
    texts: [],
    audios: []
});
```

Mi idea es hacer push a estos arrays dentro del objeto `searchItems`, si fuera javascript puro seria algo asi como `seachItems.videos.push(object)`

pero al ser un estado con useState, debo hacer uso del `setSearchItems`

Alguien sabe como hacerlo ?

tengo algo como

```
setSearchItems({
    videos: test_search.videos.filter(video =>
        video.name.includes(search)
    )
});
```

pero no funciona para nada bien.

---

Logre arreglarlo, pero ahora tengo otro problema.
Tengo este código

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (showVideos) {
        setSearchItems({
            ...searchItems,
            videos: test_search.videos.filter(video =>
                video.name.includes(search)
            )
        });
    }
    if (showTexts) {
        setSearchItems({
            ...searchItems,
            texts: test_search.texts.filter(text =>
                text.name.includes(search)
            )
        });
    }
    if (showAudios) {
        setSearchItems({
            ...searchItems,
            audios: test_search.audios.filter(audio =>
                audio.name.includes(search)
            )
        });
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [search, showVideos, showTexts, showAudios]);
```

El problema es que solo esta asignando el ultimo, en este caso los audios, los demás los deja vacíos, como podría solucionar esto ?

de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando haces uso de la función setSearchItems tienes que pasar el objeto entero, no solo el vídeo como este caso. Lo que puedes hacer es usar el operador de propagación (...) para copiar el objeto y reemplazar el campo del objeto que quieres (videos en este caso).

Ejemplo:

```
setSearchItems({...searchItems,
                videos: test_search.videos.filter(video =>
                          video.name.includes(search)
                         )
})
```

Con esto lo que haces es copiar el objeto searchItems y reemplazar el valor de videos por el que indicas con ese filter.

Espero que te funcione.
Saludos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, no sabia que el spread (...) funcionaba con objetos, entonces se hace de la misma forma que cuando pusheas un objeto a un useState([])

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tengo otra pequeña duda, crees poder revisar nuevamente la pregunta ? añadí algo mas.

Answer (score 1):

supongamos que buscaras en un listado de frutas:

codigo en tu html:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

------------codigo componente busqueda

```
var DynamicSearch = React.createClass({

  //estado inicial
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { searchString: '' };
  },

  // aqui el valor de tu texto de busqueda
  handleChange: function(event){
      this.setState({searchString:event.target.value});
  },

  render: function() {

    var fruits= this.props.items;
    var searchString = this.state.searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

    //filtrado de lista
    if(searchString.length > 0){
      fruits = fruits.filter(function(fruit){
        return fruit.name.toLowerCase().match( searchString );
      });
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.searchString} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Search!" />
        <ul>
          { fruits.map(function(fruit){ return <li>{fruit.name} </li> }) }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

});

var fruits= [
  {"name": "Manzana"}, {"name": "Platano"}, {"name": "Uva"}, {"name": "Naranja"},
  {"name": "Fresa"}, {"name": "Ciruelo"}, {"name": "Pera"}
];

React.render(
  <DynamicSearch items={ fruits} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que le sugiero hacer es utilizar el **spread operator**, es decir `...elementos` para poder obtener la copia de los elementos del objeto y también hacer uso de **desestructuración** para descomponer un objeto y así facilitar su manejo.

Ahora bien, digamos que tiene un nuevo elemento para su arreglo de videos: `mivideo` y necesitamos hacer un *push o insertarlo* en nuestro array `videos`.

Lo que haremos será lo siguiente:

```
// Nuestro State con previa data para el ejemplo
const [searchItems, setSearchItems] = useState({
    videos: [{id: 1, title: 'Video 1'}],
    texts: [{id: 1, title: 'Texto 1'}],
    audios: [{id: 1, title: 'Audio 1'}]
});

// Aplicamos DESESTRUCTURACIÓN
const {videos, texts, audios} = searchItems;
```

Ahora, **procedemos a agregarlo**:

```
    // Nuestro elemento a insertar
    let mivideo = {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Video 2'
    };

    // Agrega el elemento a nuestro array
    videos.push(mivideo);

    // Actualizamos el estado con nuestro array
    setSearchItems({
        ...searchItems, // Obtenemos elementos con un spread operator
        videos // Reemplazamos array de videos
    });
```

Salida:

[image: Salida-react-js]

Como notará, se ha agregado un nuevo elemento a nuestro array de videos. Del mismo modo, se puede hacer un `push` a los demás `arrays`.